# getting stuck with "segmentation fault" in Qt while using Qt creator to create a very simple project

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Here are my source code, a super simply one:

```
#include<QApplication>
#include<QLabel>
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
   QApplication app(argc,argv);
   QLabel *label=new QLabel("Hello world");
   label->show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

When I build it, all is good. But when I try to run it, it immediately stop, telling me that "*.exe have already stop. close it or debug it.".

So I try to debug it. After a while, it throw out a message:

```
The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system

 SINAL NAME: SIGSEGV
 SIGNAL MEANING: segmentation default
```

I went check a lot on google and stackoverflow and wikipedia. Many people say that it is caused by the wrong use of pointer. But I can't find out where the problem is. Please help.

By the way, I'm using win7 and I have try it on qt 4.8.5 and qt 5.4.0.
The compilers and debuggers are good(at least the qt creator show no error).

Should I reinstall Qt or else?

Here is wrong code(in ***qatomic_i386.h***) the debugger point out for me:

```
inline bool QBasicAtomicInt::deref()
{
        unsigned char ret;
    asm volatile("lock\n"
                 "decl %0\n"
                 "setne %1"
                 : "=m" (_q_value), "=qm" (ret)
                 : "m" (_q_value)

                 : "memory");   //this is the wrong code the debugger point out for me

 return ret != 0;
}
```

Another line in ***qstring.h***:

```
inline QString::~QString() { if (!d->ref.deref()) free(d); }
```

That's all wrong information. Thanks.

*****************code change***but the same******

```
#include<QApplication>
#include<QLabel>
#include<QDialog>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    QDialog* dialog=new QDialog;
    QLabel* label=new QLabel(dialog);
    label->setText("Hello world");
    dialog->show();
    //label->show();    it's the same with or without this

    return app.exec();
}
```

***********more changed but the same*********

```
#include<QApplication>
#include<QLabel>
#include<QDialog>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    QDialog dialog;
    QLabel label(&dialog);
    label.setText("Hello world");
    dialog.show();
    //label->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I think you need a parent main window to show your label, have a look at the docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#QLabel

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg  I changed the code. see above.

Comment: @danielfranca  I changed the code. see above.

Comment: What did you change? I still see the Label with no parent window.

Comment: @danielfranca  sorry.  Some internet delay. now it is.

Comment: @walkerlala, try to not use pointer in the 'parent qt object': `QDialog dialog`

Comment: Just tried your code and it worked fine for me, using Qt5.4.

Comment: @tvin  code changed(see above). the same

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `QLabel` is a widget like any other. Such program doesn't do much but it's perfectly valid and should run without any problem (I tested and it does, at least with Qt 4.8.4).

Comment: @danielfranca I guess there might be some issue that I don't know. It's hard to believe that a little program like this would crash. Maybe I should reinstall all of the Qt or try another version.

Comment: Try to remove the label and see if the code works only with the dialog.

Comment: Showing just the QLabel with no window should work, are you sure that you don't compile your application with a different compiler than the one used to compile Qt?

Comment: @Zlatomir Would it link together in such case?

Comment: @Bogdan if you mix two Visual Studio versions in some cases it links (it happened with VS2008 and VS 2010)

Comment: @Zlatomir Yes, you're right. It will link without problem, however, the problem is in different CRT library used by different Visuals, I forgot such case.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your .pro file that you are not trying with a console application,you must use a qwidet appplication.:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-05-04T11:12:27
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets


TARGET = testapp


TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
```

App is working good for me with your code,,,,it runs a procces_stub.exe cmd and then it show the label on a window...